# InfoPath "Sending Data to the Server" issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath, infopath-data-connections

I use SharePoint 2013.
I built a custom InfoPath form with Workflow. It worked perfect until a few days ago when a problem emerged.

Every time I try to submit the form I get "Sending Data to the Server" message for about 15 minutes. The form gets submitted, but the workflow never starts.

I tried to republish the InfoPath form and the workflow, but it did not do any good.
The rest of the forms I have are working fine, but I built them using SP 2010 platform.

Thnks

Comment: do you have a load balancer in place?

Comment: no, we don't.Do you think it is necessary to have?

Comment: does this happen to any other infopath forms, and how many servers are in your farm?

Comment: We have 3 servers. One frontend, one backend (SQL) and one Workflow/OWA server The issue happens with only one form. 
This form is the only form I created using SharePoint/InfoPath/Designer 2013

Comment: I am facing same problem.. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `Service Bus Gateway` and `Service Bus Message Broker`services are running